# App stops when switching to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, xml

When I click the button "start party" I want my Android app to switch to "activity_before_party.xml", but when I click on the button, the app stops. I have tried many things but nothing as worked... seems like a minor problem in my opinion. Thanks for the help

This is a part of "activity_home.xml" (the main page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#226B6E"
    tools:context="com.example.emili.partymate.Home"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idstartParty"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Start_Party_color"
        android:text="Start Party!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:onClick="theClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewLogs"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" />
```

This is "home.java" :

```
package com.example.emili.partymate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button startParty;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        startParty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idstartParty);
    }

    public void theClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,BeforeParty.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is "BeforeParty.java"

```
package com.example.emili.partymate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BeforeParty extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_before_party);
    }
}
```

And finally, a part of "activity_before_party.xml" (the page I want to switch to):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_before_party"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#226B6E"
    tools:context=".BeforeParty">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the error as well, otherwise it would be hard to find the problem.
Probably you have not register your `BeforeParty` activity in the `AndroidManifest`.

Should be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.your.packename">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <activity android:name=".BeforeParty" />

</manifest>
```

But again, it is just a guess. Provide more details and we can help.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change your method `theClick` for this one

```
startParty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(this,BeforeParty.class);
startActivity(i);                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
public void theClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,BeforeParty.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

with this:

```
startParty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeforeParty.class);
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(i);
                }            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this works for you

```
 startParty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, BeforeParty.class));
        }
    });
```